# What is the failure rate of rocket components?

Tags: rockets

Take a well documented case like the Saturn V. The Saturn V had about 3 million parts. What is the total number of part failures at all stages of testing? If this is in any way unclear, describe how it is unclear. This is a simple quantitative question.

Comment: Would you like your lawn mowed as well? Wash your car? Side of fries with that? I'm being a bit facetious I know, but you might ask for guidance how to locate reports that contain information that would help you work towards finding an answer, rather than order up some work. Most stackexchange questions will show some level of independent research first. What have you found so far, what is the part that's giving you trouble, etc. Take a little time and look around at other questions here and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Isn't this a direct duplicate to the closed question [What is the failure rate of rocket components?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22089/what-is-the-failure-rate-of-rocket-components), asked by the same user?

Comment: Great catch @DarkDust

Answer (score 2):

[This document](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19720005767&hterms=saturn%20failure%20rate&qs=N%3D0%26Ntk%3DAll%26Ntt%3Dsaturn%2520failure%2520rate%26Ntx%3Dmode%2520matchallpartial%26Nm%3D123%7CCollection%7CNASA%2520STI%7C%7C17%7CCollection%7CNACA) contains failure rate information for several classes of components used in the Apollo program.

There's lots of information to be found on the [NTRS](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?N=0&Ntk=All&Ntt=%22reliability%20analysis%22%20Saturn&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial).

[This document](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19660023504&hterms=reliability%20analysis%20Saturn&qs=N%3D0%26Ntk%3DAll%26Ntt%3D%2522reliability%2520analysis%2522%2520Saturn%26Ntx%3Dmode%2520matchallpartial) has a reliability analysis of some of the Saturn stages (i.e. a cumulative failure rate for the entire stage).

A report that lists all individual failures in all tests for the Saturn program may not exist, or may not be accessible on the internet. A gigantic pile of tests were done on individual components, assemblies, subsystems and systems, across 500,000 subcontractors. The important data was the aggregate ('this subsystem has an n% failure rate') and the aggregate would be communicated up the chain, leading to reports like the third link, which lists a probability of mission success for the S-IVB stage of 96.3% assuming one engine-out capability.

Comment: That document is about the S-IV, not the S-IVB. The S-IVB definitely did not have one-engine-out capability. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Very, very high. Lets do some math.

[Failure rates of common parts](http://reliabilityanalyticstoolkit.appspot.com/mechanical_reliability_data)

[Causes of rocket failure](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-major-causes-of-rocket-failures)

> USA
> Atlas V in 2007, due to a fuel leak from a faulty valve.
>
> Delta III in 2000, due to a guidance issue. Two previous Delta III launches in the late 1990s failed due to a software issue and an upper stage issue respectively.
>
> Delta IV in 2004, due to premature engine cutoff.

Etc...

> Nevertheless, the above list of launch failures has a few trends. Some common problems are
>
> Third/upper/vacuum stage problems. The vacuum stage is difficult to test on Earth, often runs on cryogenic fuel, is the last thing to go wrong, and has to operate in a bizarre environment. Some organizations have jealously guarded expertise in this area, others obviously do not.

As you can see, the software and fuel pumps are key sources of error. The riveting, structure, other mechanical parts etc are rarely involved. We also see from the first link that fuel seals and valves have relatively high failure rates in the range of 10 per million hours.

Software is not technically a part, so we will disregard that. But the fueling components are definitely important and have a high failure rate. Assuming at least 10% of the million parts in a rocket are fueling related, that's 100,000 parts that fail at a high rate. So at a 0.99999 reliability per part, and using Lussers Law relationships, that's a 36% reliability per hour.

[Rocket launch processnasps://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/launch/countd own101.html

> T-27 hours and counting
> Begin operations to load cryogenic reactants into the orbiter's fuel cell storage tanks

However, it takes at least 24 hours to fuel a rocket. So those parts are under stress potentially the entire time, resulting in a 2e-11 reliability over that period with dozens of failures. This is why you need testing.

In conclusion, a good testing program is needed to avoid having a minuscule probability of ever taking off. The failure risk is concentrated in the fuel valves and gaskets, which are weak components put under prolonged load.

Answer (score -4):

There is no documentation of the kind you are seeking. Almost nothing of the Apollo program documentation survives, if it existed in the first place.

[This](http://www.theorsociety.com/Pages/ORWiki/Reliability_1.aspx) source states about 1 failure per hour in an operational fighter jet. So extrapolate that to a rocket and you would likely see one or two failures per launch without testing, which would likely be fatal given how sensitive rockets are.

[This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.tuv.com/media/usa/aboutus_1/pressreleases/press_release_pdf/PTL_Magazine_Article.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi1jK7J_urUAhUmjlQKHYi6CT8QFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNGMVavkk1FN35pJezE-xqthq2Vqxg) source gives extremely high failure rates for PV modules. Failures exceed 10% for many components and 1% of components fail even the basic out of the box tests. So in a rocket with millions of parts that would mean thousands of failures.

The answer is somewhere in between these.

Comment: Lots of Apollo documentation survives.

Comment: [Lots of Apollo documentation survives, including down-to-the-millisecond transcripts of the missions.](https://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/mission_trans/mission_transcripts.htm)